# getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file" error when checkin mvn version

Tags: java, maven

getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file" error when checkin mvn version

My java version is 1.8.0_91 which is latest and my maven is latest as well which is 3.3.9.

This is the full error I am getting:

```
C:\Users\cverma>mvn -version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

Comment: Also, I have set the JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME variable correctly.

Comment: Verify and/or reinstall your installation, and do a media check on your disk. *Bad* (as opposed to just "unsupported") may mean you have a corrupted file.

Comment: resintalled but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem recently, after searching and trying so many things, I found the root cause, it was some older version of java also exists in your environment variables settings, whether it is in path or JAVA_HOME etc. Search carefully and I am sure you will find one.